# Optimal value of an expression involving ratio of series sums

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, optimization

Suppose there are two expressions
$$X = \sum_{i=1}^{M} a_i,$$
$$Y = \sum_{i=1}^{M} b_i. $$

Plotting the ratio $Y/X^2$ as $M$ is increased shows a U-shape profile. In other words, there should be an optimal value of $M$ such that $Y/X^2$ is minimized. Is there an analytical technique to compute the optimal $M$?

Comment: Well, without additional structure on $a_i, b_i$, there is no reason to always have a U-shape, and the minimizing $M$ could be anywhere. Assuming $a_i>0$ for all $i$ (to avoid divide-by-zero errors) you could fix a value $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and have a particular index $m>1$ such that $b_m=-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}b_i + \alpha(\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i)^2$, so that $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m b_i}{(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i)^2} = \alpha$.

Comment: This means that, to find the optimal $m \in \{1, ..., k\}$ (for some finite upper-bound $k$) you really need to look at all the $a_i$ and $b_i$ numbers, so the min complexity is $O(k)$, which is the same as a basic brute-force search that just tests all $m \in \{1, ..., k\}$ (keeping a running tally of the $a_i$ and $b_i$ sums).